# Object undefined in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I have a function which should display a textbox based on an option selected in a dropdown list. I have writen this in javascript, also I am using usercontrols. here is the partical code of javascript function.

```
function showhideeffectivedate(objIncType)
{
    var inctype=objIncType.value;   

    if(inctype=='AMC'||inctype=='AMCW'||inctype=='CMC'||inctype=='CMCHF'||inctype=='CHF')
    {


        var Objtr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number = createObj("tr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number");

        if(IsValidObj(Objtr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number))
        {  

         if(inctype=='CHF')
         {

         HideAreaCrossBrowser('tr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number',false)
         }
           else
         HideAreaCrossBrowser('tr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number',true)
            healthyfamilyMemberCheck()            
        }



    }
    else
    {


    var Objtr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number = createObj('tr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number');

    if(IsValidObj(Objtr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number))
    {
        HideAreaCrossBrowser('tr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number',true)

    }

    }
}
```

the .ascx file code which contains the control/textbox:

```
                  <tr class="Content" id="tr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number">
                    <td valign="top" colspan="2">
                        <table cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="Content" align="right" id="td_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number" width="130px">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number" CssClass="Content" runat="server" Text="Healthy Family Member Number" />&nbsp;
                                </td>
                                <td class="Content" align="left" id="td_txt_Healthy_Family_Member_Number" width="185px">
                                    <%--<asp:HiddenField runat="server" Value="td_txt_Healthy_Family_Member_Number" ID="hdn_help_11999" />--%>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Healthy_Family_Member_Number" CssClass="inputbox" onblur="" runat="server"
                                        Enabled="True" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

I tried to debug this code. This code does not check for if condition of 'CHF'. It skips the entire loop and says that the variable 'Objtr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number' has no object/undefined?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you include your `createObj()` function?

Answer (score 0):

IsValidObj is attempting to access the variable Objtr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number which is undefined.

createObj is not returning an object.

Comment: Yes. But why not? I have the text box in the usercontrol with id 'tr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Numbe' and I am creating the object for that. Then why is it not returning the object? The same code works for another text box which is displaying properly.

Comment: Assuming the code for createObj is correct, their may not be a element that exists by the ID that you are passing that method.  Double check the ID of that text box versus what you are passing to that method.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess, without seeing the `createObj()` function, is that

- since `Objtr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number` is not a valid HTML tag name, that element is not being created in the DOM
- so `createObj()` can't do anything (and won't return anything)
- so `var Objtr_lbl_Healthy_Family_Member_Number` is therefore undefined.

Comment: I used the same code for displaying another textbox in same usercontrol, it works why not this?